# Saving User(s) Email Address and Name to Database, Using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

My UI starts out with two text boxes, one for the users email address and the other for the users Name:

```
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="contact.email_address" placeholder="Email Address" /><br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="contact.name" placeholder="Name" />
```

I am leaving it as basic as I can because I have tried many different ways to get this completed and because I am moving from jQuery to AngularJS, I am getting confused on how to get this done.
I need to have a button where, if there needs to be multiple users, they click on this button, and another set of text boxes appear.  I can do this, but I do not know how to combine it with the next part.  This is what I do to add X amount of users to an array.  I wrote the HTML like the following:

```
    <body data-ng-app="controllerAsRecipient">
    <div class="form-group" id="ctrl-as-exmpl" data-ng-
         controller="SettingsController">
    <ul>
       <li data-ng-repeat="contact in contacts track by $index">
          <input type="text" data-ng-model="contact.email_address" placeholder="Email Address" /><br />
          <input type="text" data-ng-model="contact.name" placeholder="Name" />
       </li>
       <li>
          <button data-ng-click="addContact()">Add Recipients</button>
       </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

The AngularJS looks like:

```
    angular.module('controllerAsRecipient', [])
       .controller('SettingsController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.contacts = [];
            $scope.addContact = function() {
                $scope.contacts.push({ email_address: '', name: '' })
            }
       });
```

Now the part that I am stuck on is inserting the email address/name array, is how to make an AJAX request that will pass this data to the API. The parameter will be the the array of email/name values, however many there are, whether it is one or 50.  I can easily do it in jQuery, using $.ajax, but I do not know how to do it in AngularJS, as I have yet to do it.The above works fine, but I am not opposed to tearing it all apart and having it completely different, if there is an easier way to do it.  As I said, I can do this in jQuery with ease, but do not know how to do it (yet) in AngularJS. If anyone could help me, I would be grateful.  If I need to be more specific, please let me know and I will write a new question.  thank you very much in advance.

Comment: $http.post(...) is the angular call you would make. The specifics of it depend primarily on the expectations of your backend.

Comment: I am aware of the syntax, but because I have not done it before, just didn't know if anyone knew any advice on how to do the actual post and how I would pass the array, as I cannot get it to work. TIA.

Comment: Please post what you've done so far, what error(s) you receive, what the API expects, etc. Your question doesn't really provide much in the way of useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$http`, inject into your controller, and make the promise call

```
angular.module('controllerAsRecipient', [])
   .controller('SettingsController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.contacts = [];
        $scope.addContact = function() {
            $scope.contacts.push({ email_address: '', name: '' })
        };

        $scope.sendInfo = function(){
            $http({
              method: 'POST'
              url: 'your url api',
              data: contacts
            }).then(function(response){
               //if response success
            }, function(error){
               //if error 
            });
        };
   });
```

Comment: I just didn't know how to do the $http aspect, as I am used to doing $.ajax..., so I am testing this right now, I really hope it is this simple.  And if not,  that you so much for attempting to answer my question and also understanding it.  I will keep you informed, and obviously you will know if the answer  is what I needed.  I am not certain if I will have it done, perhaps or perhaps not.  Thanks again and I hope your day (and everyone else's, is going well.

Comment: remember the use of jquery inside angular provides some cases bugs. cause each one run on diferent stack of memory.  You can read about services in angularjs. wich can inject on each controller, and make the $http request also and if is in service is reusable.